# Relacionar encabezado y detalles

Tags: c#

Estoy consumiendo dos APIS

```
 private void btnOrdenesTrabajo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://fleet.cloudfleet.com/api/v1/work-orders/?createdAtFrom=2020-12-22T18:00:00.0000000Z&createdAtTo=2021-1-23T18:00:00.0000000Z&number=2596");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KEY"]);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", "", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
        List<Vehiculos> ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Vehiculos>>(response.Content);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ob;
    }

    private void btnTrabajo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var client = new RestClient("https://fleet.cloudfleet.com/api/v1/work-orders/labors/?woStartDateFrom=2020-12-22T05:00:00Z&woStartDateTo=2021-1-23T19:01:00Z&woStatus=opened");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KEY"]);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", "", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
        List<Jobs> ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Jobs>>(response.Content);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = ob;

    }
```

Cada una me devuelve una lista esa lista las pinto en un DataGrid, dando clic al botón las cargo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La primera es el encabezado la segunda el detalle, como ven tiene una relación con el **number** y **workOrderNumber** necesito enlazar el encabezado con el detalle y ya relacionados pintarlos en otro datagrid

Comment: Suena interesante. Qué has intentado?

Comment: Estoy analizando  apenas como hacerlo, he pensado  guardar estos datos en SQL SERVER  el encabezado y el detalle en tablas diferentes luego hacer la relación y con un inner join unirlas luego mostrar la consulta en un DataGrid, pero lo quiero es hacer directamente en c# sin usar SQL pero no se me ocurre como  hacerlo

Answer (score 1):

No tienes por qué guardar los resultados en ninguna base de datos. Añadirás una dependencia que no necesitas y, además, otro punto de quiebre en tu operación. Poderoso LINQ es lo que buscas (esto ha sido simplificado para que únicamente lo utilices de ejemplo:

```
 var orders = new List<WorkshopOrder>  {
                new WorkshopOrder {Id = 1},
                new WorkshopOrder {Id = 2 }
        };

 var jobs = new List<Job> { 
            new Job { Name = "Primer pedido de la segunda Orden", PedidoId = 2 } , 
            new Job { Name = "Segundo pedido de la segunda Orden", PedidoId = 2 },
            new Job { Name = "Tercero pedido de la segunda Orden", PedidoId = 2 },
            new Job { Name = "Cuarto pedido de la segunda Orden", PedidoId = 2 },
            new Job { Name = "Primer pedido de la primera Orden", PedidoId = 1 },
            new Job { Name=  "Segundo pedido de la primera Orden", PedidoId = 1 }
        };

 var workOrders = 
                       (from hd in orders
                       join det in jobs on hd.Id equals det.PedidoId
                       group det by hd into comb
                       select new OrdenCombinada
                       {
                           PedidoId=comb.Key.Id,
                           Items= comb.ToList()
                           
                       }).ToList();
```

El objeto `workOrders` es una `List<OrdenCombinada>` que tiene el Id de la Orden y la lista de jobs con ese order number:

```
 internal class OrdenCombinada
    {
       public int PedidoId { get; set; }
       public List<Item> Items { get; set;}
    }
```

Puedes utilizar workOrder como el datasource de tu datagridview. Solo tienes que elegir la forma de mostrar esos elementos.

Saludos

Comment: Esta lista   List<WorkshopOrder> de donde la tengo que sacar no entiendo muy bien  :(

Comment: Workshop order es la cabecera. En tu caso, vehículo. Jobs son los detalles

Comment: Si eso lo entendí pero lo que va dentro del List<WorkshopOrder> donde esta la referencia desde donde la saco

Comment: A qué te refieres con "referencia"

Comment: Que no se de donde sacar esa lista List<WorkshopOrder>

Comment: El segundo comentario responde esa pregunta. Workshop order es tu cabecera. En la llamada al api que resulta del método `btnOrdenesTrabajo_Click()`.